# Why didn't my total score increase by same amount that my high score increased?

Tags: angry-birds, angry-birds-space

For example, in one level, my highest score was '96,850' and then I got a better score of '98,570'.  So that means my score for this particular level should be increased by '1,720' points.

However, when I check my rankings, I found that my total score (for Pig Bang only) was only increased from '1,925,475' to '1,926,145', which is an increase of '670' points.

There are other situations where I got a better score of about '600' points but the total increased only by about '400'.  All the scores were taken as snapshots on the new iPad, so I can do calculations with good accuracy.  Does anyone know why the scores increase differently?

**Update: After some more playing, I just noticed that the Pig Bang level says I have a score of `1,961,015`, with 90 stars out of 90 stars obtained, while if I go to the Rankings of Game Center, it says my score for Pig Bang is `1,959,240` -- and this score was updated as soon as I got higher score in one level, so it looks like this score is very up to date.  But why different from `1,961,015`?**

Comment: looks like a bug to me

Comment: Which version are you running, Android or iOS? Not seeing this behavior in iOS, but just tried a real quick test.

Comment: iOS... 5.1 on the new iPad...

Comment: I just tried it and I couldn't reproduce, but it was just a quick test

Comment: Have you tried summing your scores and comparing them to the total?

Comment: it is too time consuming to sum up all 30 scores and go through all the "achievements" scores and sum them all up.  Elementary school math tells me that if my score in one level increased by 10 more points, then my total should increase by 10 more points as well.

Comment: From my experience, Angry Birds Space suffers from a number of defects related to scoring. For example, the Score Addict achievements seem to not trigger for some or trigger when they shouldn't for others (see the comments on http://www.angrybirdsnest.com/achievements/space/). I know I personally earned Episode 1 Score addict while playing Danger Zone. At that point I stopped trusting the scoring in the current release.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem is your looking at ranking. Because when you score a new highscore, you get a little higher on the ranking list. There is a difference in the highscore list and the ranking list. Ranking is your current position out of all the people who play the game. I hope this helped.